# what is the connection of event propagation in event delegation?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseclick-event, event-delegation, event-propagation

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
ul.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
  },
  true
);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2> ITEM 1 </h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2> ITEM 2 </h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

how is event propagation involved in this event listener? (is it involved at all?) since changing the third argument of the event listener does nothing in this code snippet, I can't understand the connection of event propagation here

in the above code; `event.target` always refers to the `h2` element if we click on it, and never refers to the `li`, even though we have enabled capturing phase in this example.

Comment: There's a [nice explanation](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) of how the event propagation works.

Comment: @Teemu I already know how event propagation works, I just don't know the connection of event propagation in this particular example

Comment: I didn't write that comment, Teemu did.

Comment: I don't think the `useCapture` option makes a difference when you don't have event listeners at multiple levels.

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters): "_Event bubbling and capturing are two ways of propagating events that occur in an element that is nested within another element, when both elements have registered a handle for that event. The event propagation mode determines the order in which elements receive the event_" You've attached only a single listener, the phase has no effect.

Comment: @Teemu thanks!!

Comment: BTW, you'll get `li` as the event target when clicking on the list item symbol, H2 element fills the rest of the `li` element so that there's no clickable surface.